# Automatically call library function on application startup

Tags: android

Say I have some library `library.aar` and it has a function called `initialize`. I also have an app and the gradle file has been modified to include `library.aar` as a dependency.

Rather than calling `library.initialize();` from within the application code, I want `library.initialize()` to be called automatically when the application starts up.

Is this possible? Perhaps there is a way for my library to listen for application startup and then call initialize on itself?